# Spring AOP caching returning Arraylist instead of expected Object

Tags: java, spring, caching, aop, ehcache

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.vuelogix.collygo.to.TODatapointTemplate
at com.vuelogix.collygo.service.DatapointTemplateService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3af4fe56.findById(<generated>)
at com.vuelogix.collygo.service.DataPointService.addToHistory(DataPointService.java:157)
at com.vuelogix.collygo.service.DataPointService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$201d1115.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor$1.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:52)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:185)
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:60)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
at com.vuelogix.collygo.service.DataPointService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8b1eaf10.addToHistory(<generated>)
at com.vuelogix.m2m.store.StorageProcessor.process(StorageProcessor.java:36)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:97)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:51)
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:113)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessParallel(MulticastProcessor.java:711)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.access$200(MulticastProcessor.java:82)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$1.call(MulticastProcessor.java:292)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$1.call(MulticastProcessor.java:277)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is the method i tried to cache.

```
public TODatapointTemplate findById(int id) {
    logger.debug("findById:: finding by Id :" + id
            + ".. status:: processing");
    DatapointTemplate datapointTemplate = datapointTemplateRepository
            .findOne(id);
    logger.debug("findById:: found DatapointTemplate for id : " + id);
    TODatapointTemplate toDatapointTemplate = null;
    try {
        if (Utility.nullCheck(datapointTemplate)) {
            toDatapointTemplate = mapper.map(datapointTemplate,
                    TODatapointTemplate.class);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("findById:: Exception : " + e.getMessage() + e);
    }
    logger.debug("findById:: finding by Id :" + id + ".. status:: done");
    return toDatapointTemplate;
}
```

Cache configuration

```
<cache:advice id="DatapointTemplateServiceCacheAdvice"
    cache-manager="cacheManager">
    <cache:caching cache="DatapointTemplateService">
        <cache:cacheable method="findById" key="#id.toString()"/>
    </cache:caching>
```

ehcache config

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd" name="rootCache">


<cache
name="DatapointTemplateService"
maxEntriesLocalHeap="20000"
eternal="false"
timeToIdleSeconds="600"
timeToLiveSeconds="1200"
/>


</ehcache>
```

I am getting class cast expection when i enable this cache. I have overridden the hashcode and equals methods of TODatapointTemplate but the problem still persists

Comment: Did you clear cache after this change? since old records will be still there.

Comment: how to clear the cache??

Comment: This method public TODatapointTemplate findById(int id) {}. did this method returned arrrayList before and you changed it now to return just one object? if that is the case, then you have to wait to cache eviction of previous arraylist OR manually clear or programmatically clear ehcache and check it.

Comment: ok, i will try to clear.. This method public TODatapointTemplate findById(int id) {}. did this method returned arrrayList before?? No..

Comment: Also can you paste the code from where you are calling and assigning this. how are you doing that part?

Comment: the method which i am trying to cache is a service method findByid(where id is primarykey)...this method is called from multiple places from my application..for loading DatapointTemplates

Comment: Can you add the configuration bit that applies the advice to classes? I am wondering if it could end caching unrelated findById methods from other classes.

Comment: mistake was two different type of objects (Arraylist and TODatapointTemplate) was added to same cache ie,   <cache:caching cache="DatapointTemplateService">..